# iOS iPad UIActionSheet Issue

Tags: objective-c, ios, uipopovercontroller, uiactionsheet

I am currently developing an application which needs an option to 'share' using multiple services; such as email, twitter.

To to this, I have a `UIBarButtonItem` coded in and when touched, it triggers this:

```
UIActionSheet *sheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] 
                            initWithTitle:@""
                            delegate:self
                            cancelButtonTitle:nil
                            destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                            otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [sheet addButtonWithTitle:@"Email"];
    [sheet addButtonWithTitle:@"Tweet"];
    [sheet addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];

    sheet.cancelButtonIndex = sheet.numberOfButtons-1;

    [sheet showFromRect:self.view.bounds inView:self.view animated:YES];
    [sheet release];
```

In conjunction with this to detect which button is selected:

```
clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (buttonIndex == actionSheet.cancelButtonIndex) { return; }
    switch (buttonIndex) {
        case 0:
        {

            [self emailThis];
            break;
        }
        case 1:
        {
            [self tweetThis];
            break;
        }
    }
```

This works a treat on the iPhone. But unfortunately it displays incorrectly on the iPad. It looks like it is trying to display the `UIPopoverController`, but it is positioned center of the navbar with practically no height.

I have looked into using the UIPopoverController, but I cannot seem to find out how to use it with buttons. Is there anyway I can adapt the code above to properly display the buttons, as it's trying to already.

Many thanks,

Ryan

PS: I'm new to objective-c/iOS coding, so please be specific. Thank you :)

**EDIT:**
I have tried using:

```
[sheet showFromBarButtonItem:[self share] animated:YES];
```

But it doesn't work. Here is my code for the button:

```
UIBarButtonItem *share = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                                initWithTitle:@"Share"                                            
                                style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered 
                                target:self 
                                action:@selector(loadShare)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = share;
    [share release];
```

Also here is the code in the .h file:

```
@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {
UIBarButtonItem *share;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *share;
```

Here is the debug error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderArray
>   initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction target:self action:@selector(actionPhotoShare:)] autorelease];
```

...

```
-(void)actionPhotoShare:(id)sender
{
actionSheetShare = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil 
                                                              delegate:self 
                                                     cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                                destructiveButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"ActionSheet_Cancel", @"")
                                                     otherButtonTitles:NSLocalizedString(@"ActionSheet_Email", @""),nil];

if (IS_DEVICE_IPAD) {
    [actionSheetShare showFromBarButtonItem:sender animated:YES];
}else {
    [actionSheetShare showInView:self.view];
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of [sheet showFromRect], use [sheet showFromBarButtonItem], and point it to your Share UIBarButtonItem.
Note: you may need to create an IBOutlet or ivar for your UIBarButtonItem if you don't have one already, but that's extremely simple and I'm guessing you can do that.

Comment: Hi using this "[sheet showFromBarButtonItem]", it displays this warning and also crashes if touched: Instance method '-showFromBarButtonItem' not found (return type defaults to 'id').

Comment: you need to pass in your UIBarButtonItem to this method. Read it's documentation. My code was just a hint, not a complete statement.

Comment: Hi, please see my edit. I have done that, but there's an error. Thanks

Comment: @melsam, hi, how to move to right/left? My arrow not centered in the middle (horizontal middle) of the barButtonItem, if I use showFromBarButtonItem

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you are using `showFromRect` with the rect being the entire screen. That means the popup is placing the "arrow" the best it can to center on the screen. What you want is either `showFromBarButtonItem` or pass in the rect (`self.shareButtonItem.frame`) of the button.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. But using "[sheet showFromRect:self.shareButtonItem.frame inView:self.view animated:YES];" I get the error:Property 'shareButtonItem' not found on object of type 'DetailViewController *'. I have also tried "[sheet showFromBarButtonItem]" from Melsam's answer, but had no luck with that.